# Is it possible with Python to code G key to move channels up and down in the Dopesheet editor?

Tags: python, interface

Just like we are able to translate most elements in Blender, it would be really nice to be able to do it there. Is it possible?

Comment: Well, in the form you've asked it, the answer is "yes," but that's probably not what you're looking for. Incidentally, the answer to any question that starts with "is it possible to write code that would..." is almost ALWAYS "yes." It is possible. A better question is "would it be worth it." The BEST question would be "What Python command sets a new hotkey in Blender," or "how do I get my Blender script to listen for a keypress without it just running all the time?" Try to be specific.

Comment: Actually, "yes" would be enough, thank you! Sometimes I think something is possible, then look for a way to do it, and after a lot of time invested, turns out it isn't possible. Also, every little usability improvement is always worth it if you repeat the same task every day, even if I have to expend a ridiculous amount of time figuring out how to implement it. P.S.: I'm sorry if the question bothered you!

Comment: Are you asking if you can use python to make dope sheet channels drag+drop with the G key to change their position in the list?

Comment: You can move the position of channels within each Action group up and down using the Page Up/Down keys, not sure if you already knew that.

Comment: I know about the keys, I want indeed to drag+drop with G key.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the default keys are <kbd>⇞ Page up</kbd> and <kbd>⇟ Page down</kbd>, the setting can be found in keyboard input under Animation Channels.

[image]

The python path is `bpy.context.window_manager.keyconfigs.active.keymaps['Animation Channels'].keymap_items['anim.channels_move']` with the property `type` being the key used, `properties.direction` is the direction the selected item is moved. You will want to loop through the `keymap_items` as you will find four `keymap_items['anim.channels_move']` entries, up one line, down one line, to the top and to the bottom.

You should look at [adding keymaps to an addon](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_75_release/info_tutorial_addon.html?highlight=keymap) to make the changes properly.